# aws kinesis get-records returns empty array

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am playing around with Kinesis, and I tried a very simple example

I first put a sample record

```
aws kinesis put-records --records "Data=Test data - hemant,PartitionKey=20150421" --stream-name mystream
```

I get back

```
{
"FailedRecordCount": 0,
"Records": [
    {
        "SequenceNumber": "49549975503580743304507290523786194552567002802960728066",
        "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000"
    }
]}
```

So put appears to have worked. Now I am trying to retrive back this record, first, by getting the shard-iterator, and then calling the gert-record using the returned shard-iterator.
The get-shard-iterator returns

```
aws kinesis get-shard-iterator --stream-name cakestream --shard-id 0 --shard-iterator-type LATEST
{
"ShardIterator": "AAAAAAAAAAEna1yL0ccbircK95wu6WRfN7LamlaXL5bZ1GzaFrUcSU8S74o4Pus59Z0XmdaMamdvz4tv3qKuPxpomz/Eeg671gVUKNHUDruAKyA4pjWRP37VI1K5w/kLqpBo49YsCKHMxcduaN6GdeCXL4QMSgvH9Aqi7leRuIr2T1w4MeqjhlcM1iz8icaWGlHfUVCbgtY="}
```

And now I try to get the records using that shard-iterator

```
aws kinesis get-records --shard-iterator "AAAAAAAAAAEna1yL0ccbircK95wu6WRfN7LamlaXL5bZ1GzaFrUcSU8S74o4Pus59Z0XmdaMamdvz4tv3qKuPxpomz/Eeg671gVUKNHUDruAKyA4pjWRP37VI1K5w/kLqpBo49YsCKHMxcduaN6GdeCXL4QMSgvH9Aqi7leRuIr2T1w4MeqjhlcM1iz8icaWGlHfUVCbgtY="{
"NextShardIterator": "AAAAAAAAAAE4lTq/jqanuj+xsULhl6QQeykzToObYDoaukearHkQfed/keYjgxzwfxkDXlBJBAOVLsk3pI9d0EwQWn5NmJ9poCL9M1wGDe2M42fgmp1EdK0WJGI1zG7TMi8m1bGQ6qDL05zf7gCtK5/xod6Vw/Gr98bsdQ8Ewp3U57FuHxZ29LUUbYp3AoN7CbUTD5rtqzU=",
"Records": []}
```

So, my question is why am I not getting back my data?

Answer (score 7):

The LATEST shard iterator will return all records put into the stream **after** it was created.

So, if you'd like to see your records, you'll have to put them after you create the iterator, and then request for get-records.

Answer (score 2):

As Paedolos mentioned, LATEST shard iterator will return only the records put after the iterator is created.

If you would like to process all the records in the stream from beginning, you need to create TRIM_HORIZON shard iterator.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is stream name mismatch.

You have put your records in **mystream** stream but you are trying to fetch those records from **cakestream** stream.

Answer (score 0):

Few things here...

- It is not guaranteed that you would end up getting your records in the very first attempt. You will have to loop through the iterators(next iterator is returned with every getRecords() call) to eventually get all your data.
- There are various ways to get the first iterator. You might want to use the correct one based on your use case

  Valid Values: 
  AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER | AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER | TRIM_HORIZON | LATEST | AT_TIMESTAMP