# Issues while retrieving records from aws kinesis data stream

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried to put a record in aws kinesis data stream with the following aws cli command,

### Request:

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name Live_DataStream  --partition-key 123 --data testdata
```

### Response:

{
    "ShardId": "shardId-000000000001",
    "SequenceNumber": "49583432609061722809096316034912211811585750778783989778"
}

But when i try to get the record from data stream, the records are empty

### Request:

```
aws kinesis get-records --shard-iterator AAAAAAAAAAGoE8kuRTLaqFMdZQVydTXl5P3B1+KHP4k66Kj1EXirRlqAliCFLRrKC43hcilLXz/D//9Mr27TqLxxRtFqSnOeijhCuTasgcQizgHSTdMlxaw2NF25ToInQ8rXQ37JOfHztOER5TkRsYD4fzZmERsT+vbseCCIJ+XLbKopo8hYpVbFCVwJzhg9W4GH2TjyxQH1yDhCO16/SsXS5GGWKhlO
```

### Response:

{
    "Records": [],
    "NextShardIterator": "AAAAAAAAAAHi88xL082GH7oCyl+FxrNw8utchS+7mQx/gInRUnNcLu5vUc/Zqs78hOjbdwsszUZlghsT1b4N6Au9LJRnY5xe0CRZFG4bnq100r6NkeHIBxvt1WgvLbVD372ZOCvqa1JKyp0Tl3/qJKzL57W48H2pzwjFn6kxrWXESj2TN+Xs5J+DK6mUIARfsTUfdvPK15JEGQjJGXapZyEs9l9BJh3Y",
    "MillisBehindLatest": 0
}

I tried many a times but the records are still empty and its not retrieving that "test data". Kindly provide me with solutions to solve this issue

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804150/aws-kinesis-get-records-returns-empty-array?rq=1

Comment: aws kinesis get-shard-iterator --shard-id shardId-000000000000 --shard-iterator-type TRIM_HORIZON --stream-name xyz will return with the shard iterator

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the shard-iterator? probably you are obtaining the iterator that points one element after the one you inserted, try with "TRIM_HORIZON", it should work.